# Как ограничить Бота? Python Telegram bot

Tags: python, telegram, бот, chat

У меня назрел вопрос: как ограничить бота (пишу на языке Python)? То есть, как сделать ТАК, чтобы Telegram БОТ работал ТОЛЬКО В МОЕЙ группе?

То есть, если ЧЕЛОВЕК захочет написать БОТУ, то БОТ его проигнуорирует и даже не будет никак реагировать.

Или если ЧЕЛОВЕК обнаглеет и захочет добавить МОЕГО БОТА в свою группу, то у него ничего не выйдет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, что вы можете проверять идентификатор группы при получении сообщения ботом, если группа ваша, то давать ответ, иначе не реагировать. Вы не указали какую библиотеку используете, поэтому дам **пример** **с использованием [pyTelegramBotAPI](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI)**:

```
import telebot
    
bot = telebot.TeleBot('ВАШ_ТОКЕН"')
    
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
def send_welcome(message):
    cid = message.chat.id # Получаем ID группы (чата)
    if cid == 'ВАШ_ИДЕНТИФИКАТОР_ГРУППЫ':
        bot.reply_to(message, 'Привет, как ты?')
    
    bot.infinity_polling()
```

Comment: Помогло. Только нужно было убрать '', а так все норм :)